# PHP PrestaShop Webservice language resource error

Tags: prestashop

I am using platform webservice (1.6) and I don't have problems accessing to categories, products resources but when I try to access languages resource I got error.

Also with a direct request about schema/synopsis I got error.

Example:

aut_key@127.0.0.1/presta/api/products?schema=synopsis I got extended schema information

aut_key@127.0.0.1/presta/api/languages?schema=synopsis I got following

"Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors."

Setting debug mode I got:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message 'This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 401. That means: Unauthorized.' in C:\Ampps\www\test\PSWebServiceLibrary.php:92 Stack trace: #0 C:\Ampps\www\test\PSWebServiceLibrary.php(296): PrestaShopWebservice->checkStatusCode(401) #1 C:\Ampps\www\test\presta.php(93): PrestaShopWebservice->get(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Ampps\www\test\PSWebServiceLibrary.php on line 92

Status 401. Unauthorize doesn't make any sense since if I try to get orders schema with same settings no errors.

Any idea?

I am using following official PSWebServiceLibrary

https://raw.github.c...viceLibrary.php

Thank you

Comment: Just tested, and no errors. Are you sure that you have set the right permission for that auth_key?

Comment: yes thank you it was a right permission problem ... thank you!